# ember controller getProperties return "undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I m having an issue with forms in ember, the `this.getProperties` inside  controller returns `undefined` for all properties. Here is my code:

settings.hbs:

```
<form {{action 'saveSettings' on='submit'}}>

<label for="email">Email</label>
<p>
{{input id='email' placeholder='Enter Email' value=model.email}}
</p>
<label for="name">Name</label>

<p>
{{input id='name' placeholder='Enter Name' value=model.name}}
</p>
<label for="surname">Surname</label>

<p>
{{input id='surname' placeholder='Enter Surname' value=model.surname}}
</p>
<label for="skype">Skype</label>

<p>
{{input id='skype' placeholder='Enter Skype' value=model.skype}}
</p>
<label for="phone">Phone</label>

<p>
{{input id='phone' placeholder='Enter Phone' value=model.phone}}
</p>
<label for="city">City</label>

<p>
{{input id='city' placeholder='Enter City' value=model.city}}
</p>

<label for="country">Country</label>

<p>
{{input id='country' placeholder='Enter Country' value=model.country}}
</p>

<button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

settings.js (controller)

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  actions: {
    saveSettings() {

      let {
        email, name, surname, skype, phone, city, country
      } = this.getProperties('email', 'name', 'surname', 'skype',
        'phone',
        'city', 'country');

      var user = this.get('model');
      user.set('email', email);
      user.set(
        'name', name);
      user.set('surname', surname);
      user.set('skype',
        skype);
      user.set('phone', phone);
      user.set('city', city);
      user
        .set('country', country);

      user.save();
    }
  }

});
```

settings.js (route)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.find('user', 'me');
  }

});
```

When load the page all inputs shows the correct value, but when submit the form all properties are null. I take a few hours stuck here and i don't see why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your controller has no such properties like you expect it to have. From your controller's code I see there are none. The Settings controller has only one action handler defined (`saveSettings()`), nothing else. The form is filled with data correctly because it's the model data (i.e. `{{input .... value=model.email}}`), not the controller data.

I won't describe how to work with controller properties because I bet what you want to do is to update your user. It's a two way binding, thus no explicit property modification is necessary. I think this code should do the work:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  actions: {
    saveSettings() {
      var user = this.get('model');

      // here your user should already have updated values, no need to set them explicitly

      // update the user also on backend
      user.save();
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Pavol! Works like a charm. Very helpful! Finally I understood how controllers and templates works.